# Covariance of Box<dyn FnOnce(T)> in rust

Tags: rust, lifetime, variance, contravariance

I have a function that expects a short lived object. I would expect that I would be able to always pass it a long lived object. But I am getting a strange error when I try to encode that:

```rust
type F<'arg> = Box<dyn FnOnce(&'arg ())>;
fn contravar<'small, 'large: 'small>(f: F<'small>) -> F<'large> {
    f
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=976d6bff8e3e107fff3b5d093bb4cddb)

Particularly:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:3:5
  |
2 | fn contravar<'small, 'large: 'small>(f: F<'small>) -> F<'large> {
  |              ------  ------ lifetime `'large` defined here
  |              |
  |              lifetime `'small` defined here
3 |     f
  |     ^ function was supposed to return data with lifetime `'large` but it is returning data with lifetime `'small`
  |
  = help: consider adding the following bound: `'small: 'large`
```

It seems like `F` is invariant for its argument but I would have guessed that it's contravariant. Am I missing something? Is there a way to make `F<'arg>` *really* contravariant for `'arg`?

Edit: it looks like the "problem" is that rust wants to treat all generic traits the same (including Fn/FnMut/FnOnce). My opinion is that those 3 are and should be treated special especially given that they are the only way to refer to closures. For that reason I opened an [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/100728)

Comment: This looks like a bug. Maybe you should report it?

Comment: From what I've been reading the past hour, variance appears to get real tricky around trait objects, which is presumably why this gets rejected by the compiler. But it does look like it should work. It certainly works with `fn` pointers.

Comment: It's strange, if I change F from a type alias to a newtype I would assume that the compiler would decide that F is contravariant for it's argument and it wouldnt matter wether it's a trait object or not. Alas, that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Rust Reference's page on [Subtyping and Variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/subtyping.html#variance) documents that, as of Rust 1.63.0, `fn(T) -> ()` is contravariant over `T` and that `dyn Trait<T> + 'a` is **invariant** over `T`.

`FnOnce`, `FnMut` and `Fn` are traits, so that means `dyn FnOnce(&'a ())` is unfortunately invariant over `&'a ()`.

```
// Compiles
pub fn contravariant<'a, 'b: 'a>(x: fn(&'a ())) -> fn(&'b ()) { x }

// Doesn't compile
pub fn contravariant2<'a, 'b: 'a>(x: Box<dyn FnOnce(&'a ())>) -> Box<dyn FnOnce(&'b ())> { x }
```

---

> Is there a way to wrap `FnOnce` somehow to convince the compiler of the correct variance?

Here's what I could come up with using `unsafe` code. Note that I'm not making any guarantees as to whether this is sound or not. I don't know of any way to do this without `unsafe` code.

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait Erased {}

impl<T> Erased for T {}

pub struct VariantBoxedFnOnce<Arg, Output> {
    boxed_real_fn: Box<dyn Erased + 'static>,
    _phantom_fn: PhantomData<fn(Arg) -> Output>,
}

impl<Arg, Output> VariantBoxedFnOnce<Arg, Output> {
    pub fn new(real_fn: Box<dyn FnOnce(Arg) -> Output>) -> Self {
        let boxed_real_fn: Box<dyn Erased + '_> = Box::new(real_fn);
        let boxed_real_fn: Box<dyn Erased + 'static> = unsafe {
            // Step through *const T because *mut T is invariant over T
            Box::from_raw(Box::into_raw(boxed_real_fn) as *const (dyn Erased + '_) as *mut (dyn Erased + 'static))
        };
        Self {
            boxed_real_fn,
            _phantom_fn: PhantomData,
        }
    }

    pub fn call_once(self, arg: Arg) -> Output {
        let boxed_real_fn: Box<Box<dyn FnOnce(Arg) -> Output>> = unsafe {
            // Based on Box<dyn Any>::downcast()
            Box::from_raw(Box::into_raw(self.boxed_real_fn) as *mut Box<dyn FnOnce(Arg) -> Output>)
        };
        boxed_real_fn(arg)
    }
}

pub fn contravariant<'a, 'b: 'a>(x: VariantBoxedFnOnce<&'a (), ()>) -> VariantBoxedFnOnce<&'b (), ()> { x }

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    fn foo(_x: &()) {}

    #[test]
    pub fn check_fn_does_not_require_static() {
        let f = VariantBoxedFnOnce::new(Box::new(foo));
        let x = ();
        f.call_once(&x);
    }

    #[test]
    pub fn check_fn_arg_is_contravariant() {
        let f = VariantBoxedFnOnce::new(Box::new(foo));
        let g = contravariant(f);
        let x = ();
        g.call_once(&x);
    }
}
```

Here, `VariantBoxedFnOnce` is limited to functions taking one argument.

The trick is to store a type-erased version of the `Box<dyn FnOnce(Arg) -> Output>` such that `Arg` disappears, because we don't want the variance of `VariantBoxedFnOnce<Arg, Output>` to depend on `Box<dyn FnOnce(Arg) -> Output>` (which is invariant over `Arg`). However, there's also a `PhantomData<fn(Arg) -> Output>` field to provide the proper contravariance over `Arg` (and covariance over `Output`).

We can't use `Any` as our erased type, because only `'static` types implement `Any`, and we have a step in `VariantBoxedFnOnce::new()` where we have a `Box<dyn Erased + '_>` where `'_` is not guaranteed to be `'static`. We then immediately "transmute" it into `'static`, to avoid having a redundant lifetime parameter on `VariantBoxedFnOnce`, but that `'static` is a lie (hence the `unsafe` code). `call_once` "downcasts" the erased type to the "original" `Box<dyn FnOnce(Arg) -> Output>`, except that `Arg` and `Output` may be different from the original due to variance.

Comment: You seem to be right, but it still doesn't make sense. Is there a way to wrap `FnOnce` somehow to convince the compiler of the correct variance?

Comment: Have a look at my edit.

Comment: Your `Erased` trait is very similar to `Any`. Is there a reason for not having used it?

Comment: Very informative, thank you very much!

Comment: @BlackBeans Yes, I already explain it in the last paragraph. (I just rephrased it because it was unclear.) Cheating with lifetimes in Rust is not trivial!

Comment: I just noticed that you do `Box::into_raw(self.boxed_real_fn) as *mut Box<dyn FnOnce(Arg) -> Output>` where it should probably be `Box::into_raw(self.boxed_real_fn) as *mut (dyn FnOnce(Arg) -> Output)`, but the latter does is not accepted.

Comment: No, `*mut Box<...>` is correct; the `FnOnce` is really double-boxed here. `Box<dyn FnOnce(Arg) -> Output>` is already a fat pointer, and we need to erase the whole `Box` type, so we need to wrap the box in another box. `dyn Erased + 'static` is `Box<dyn FnOnce(Arg) -> Output>` erased.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to replace the outer box with something else like a union type to avoid the allocation and indirection but my initial attempts failed, do you think it's possible?

Comment: Well, we could use `Box::into_raw()` on the `Box<dyn FnOnce(Arg) -> Output>` to turn it into a `*mut dyn FnOnce(Arg) -> Output`, then we could turn it into a different `*mut _` and store that, but it needs to remain a fat pointer or we'd lose the vtable. `*mut (dyn Erased + 'static)` would probably work, but then we'd need to implement `Drop` manually by casting it back to the correct `Box` type.